# want to know the reason about postgresql connection

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to connect postgresql db using psycopg2 and I succeded.

But I want to know the reason how I succeded because I input dbname only like this.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='', dbname='test', user='', password='', port='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the empty fields, it used the defaults.  Apparently those worked.